# Measurable rectangles inside a non-null set

Tags: measure-theory

Consider $[0,1]^2$ with Lebesgue measure $\mu$.  Let $D\subseteq [0,1]^2$ be measurable with $0<\mu(D)<1$.  Can you find $A,B\subseteq[0,1]$ measurable with $\mu(A)\mu(B)>0$ and yet $\mu(D\cap (A\times B))=0$?  (That is, I want to find a non-null rectangle which is essentially inside the complement of $D$).

Some thoughts:

- By regularity, we may suppose that $D$ is open, and that $A$ and $B$ are closed
- If $D$ is not dense, then the answer is easily "yes".  So we may suppose that $D$ is open and dense.
- You can then write $D$ as a countable union of open rectangles with rational coordinates.  Treating each one at a time, we can delete null sets from A or B.  Repeating countably many times shows that if $A$ and $B$ exist, then actually, we can choose them with $D \cap (A\times B) = \emptyset$.

I somewhat suspect that this is false, but I cannot find a counter-example (I can't get the usual trick of, say, covering the rationals by small open balls to work).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The existence of a counterexample is implied by Theorem 2.1 of Kendall and Montana's paper "[Small sets and Markov transition densities](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030441490200090X)".  Below is an excerpt from pages 180-182, including the beginning of the section for context.

This question is answered with a different approach in Halmos's *[Problems for mathematicians, young and old](http://books.google.com/books?id=VvTuAAAAMAAJ)*.  Problem, Hint, and Solution 14.E are given below the Kendall and Montana excerpt.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

And here's Halmos:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Brilliant!  And if I could +1 twice for including scans of the article, I would.  That is indeed more complicated than I expected...

Comment: Btw, did you just happen to know this paper?  Or did you manage to search for it?  If the latter, any hints on how you found it??

Comment: @Matthew: I did not know about it in advance.  I don't remember the exact Google search, but it included `"measurable rectangle"`, and probably `null`.  This also led me to Halmos.

Comment: I cannot follow Halmos's proof. First, I do not understand the significance of the second-to-last paragraph, where he shows that $D \cap (E-F)$ includes a non-empty open set; this fact seems to not be used anywhere. Next, in the last paragraph, he claims for *each* real number $y$ that $(\delta^{-1}(D) \cap (E \times F))^y = (D+y) \cap E$, which is only true in case of $y \in F$; this latter condition is used implicitly in the last line of the three-line equation. This restriction on $y$ completely kills the calculation of $\lambda(\delta^{-1}(D) \cap (E\times F))$ - or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need to work so hard. Let $S$ be the unit square $[0, 1]^2$, $D = \{(x, y) \in S : x + y \notin \mathbb{Q}\}$. Then both $D$ and $S \backslash D$ are positive rectangle free (for $D$, use Steinhaus theorem). Now divide $S$ into four equal squares and choose $E \subset S$ which is the union of $D$ relativized to 1st and 3rd square and $S \backslash D$ relativized to 2nd and 4th square. Then, $E$ has area $1/2$ and both $E$ and $S \backslash E$ are positive rectangle free.