# Monotone convergence theorem on a function of two variables (integrating over one variable)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, measurable-functions, pointwise-convergence

Consider a measurable space $\big( E \times F, \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F} \big)$, an $(\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F})$-measurable and positive function $f$, and a measure $\nu$ on $\big( F, \mathcal{F} \big)$.

Consider the function $\nu f$ defined as

\begin{align*}
\nu f \colon E & \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}_+ \\
x & \longmapsto \nu f (x) = \int_F \nu(dy) f(x,y)
\end{align*}

Under what conditions on $\nu$, is $\nu f$ $\mathcal{E}$-measurable and positive?

**My attempt**

I would proceed by showing first the measurability of indicator functions in $(\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F})$, then measurability of simple functions, and finally measurability of positive measurable functions by monotone convergence theorem. This would allow to make no requirements on $\nu$. Here it is.

Consider a simple function $\mathbb{I}_{A \times B}$, where $A \in \mathcal{E}$ and $B \in \mathcal{F}$.

Then, $\nu \mathbb{I}_{A \times B} = \nu \mathbb{I}_A \mathbb{I}_B = \nu(B) \mathbb{I}_A $ is $\mathcal{E}$-measurable as it is the product of a constant $\nu(B)$ and $\mathbb{I}_A$. Of course, $A \in \mathcal{E}$ and $B \in \mathcal{F}$.

So, for any measurable rectangle $A \times B \in \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}$, the function $\nu \mathbb{I}_{A \times B}$ is $\mathcal{E}$- measurable and positive.

Now, consider the simple function $f = \sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n \mathbb{I}_{A_n \times B_n}$, with $a_n$ postive $\forall \ n \geq 1$. It is $(\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F})$-measurable and positive as a linear combination of measuarble indicator functions.

Then, $\nu \big( \sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n \mathbb{I}_{A_n \times B_n} \big) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \big( a_n \ \nu \mathbb{I}_{A_n \times B_n} \big) $ is $\mathcal{E}$-measurable as it is a linear combination of $\mathcal{E}$-measurable and positive functions from the previous step.

Finally, consider an arbitrary $(\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F})$-measurable and positive function $f$. Then, $\exists \big( f_n \big)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset (\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F})_+$, a sequence of $(\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F})$-measurable and positive simple functions, such that $f_n \nearrow f$. Then, one can apply monotone convergence theorem with respect to $\nu$ and claim that

$\nu f = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \nu f_n$ **is $\mathcal{E}$-measurable** and positive as the limit of a sequence of $\mathcal{E}$-measurable and positive functions $\nu f_n$.

**The issue**

My textbook proves the measurability of $\nu f$ under the assumption that $\nu$ is **$\Sigma$-finite**. So, this means that my proof above is not correct, i.e. $\nu f$ is not necessarily measurable. I do not know what is wrong in my proof: I suspect issues can arise when applying the monotone convergence theorem, but I cannot imagine how, because the limit of $\mathcal{E}$-measurable functions is supposed to be $\mathcal{E}$-measurable itself. Any help would be much appreciated. I can provide a potential counterexample of a non-$\Sigma$-finite measure $\nu$ such that $\nu f$ is not $\mathcal{E}$-measurable even if $f$ is $\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}$-measurable an positive.

Comment: How do we obtain a sequence of rectangular simple functions from the sequence $(f_n)$?

Comment: I thought that this is the same as in the case where $(f_n$) is a sequence of functions of one variable, which is done regularly in the textbook. So, in the case with one variable, $f_i(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n \mathbb{I}_{A_n}$. And with some cumbersome notation (accounting for both the $i$ and the $n$'s within each $f_i$, one constructs a sequence of increasing simple functions as above, so that the limit is $f$. In two variables, the only difference would be that $A_n \times B_n$ are bound to grow together. But I believe that one can rearrange the sequence of rectangles so that (follows next)

Comment: But I believe that one can rearrange the sequence of rectangles so that the rectangles are of the form $A_n \times B_m$: one has two indexes $n$ and $m$, the rectangles are not constrained in any way, and the sequence over $n,m \geq 1$ is still countable. Is this not correct? And most importantly, do you think this is the point that makes my attempt of proof wrong?

Comment: I dont think that we can just assume that $(f_n)$ can be chosen as simple rectangular functions see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399787/approximate-a-measurable-function-by-simple-functions-in-a-product-measure-space) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have confused yourself by conflating two different notions of "simple function".

Here I'll use the term "simple function" in its usual sense, for a function of the form $f(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n 1_{C_n}$ where $C_n$ is an arbitrary $\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}$-measurable set.  Note that $C_n$ does not have to be of the form $A_n \times B_n$.

I'll use the term "rectangle function" for a simple function with the special property that each $C_n$ *is* of the form $C_n = A_n \times B_n$.  This is what you were calling a "simple function" in your proof, and I think that is the source of the confusion.

It is true that each measurable function $f$ is approximated by a monotone increasing sequence of **simple** functions.  However, your argument did not prove that $\nu f(x)$ is measurable for an arbitrary **simple** function $f$.  This step is where you would need to use the hypothesis of $\sigma$-finiteness.

You did prove that $\nu f(x)$ is measurable when $f$ is a **rectangle** function.  But it is not true that every measurable function is approximated by a monotone increasing sequence of **rectangle** functions.

For a counterexample, let $E = F = [0,1]$, and consider the "diagonal" set $D = \{ (x,x) : x \in [0,1]\} \subset E \times F$.  Let $f = \mathbb{1}_D$.  Now let $g = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \mathbb{1}_{A_n \times B_n}$ be a positive rectangle function in which, without loss of generality, every $a_n > 0$ and every $A_n, B_n$ are nonempty.  If $g \le f$ then necessarily $A_n \times B_n \subset D$ for every $n$.  But this is only possible if $A_n = B_n = \{x\}$ for some $x$, i.e. they must be singletons.  Therefore $g$ is only nonzero at a finite number of points (has finite support).

Hence if $f_n$ is a sequence of positive rectangle functions with $f_n \le f$, then each $f_n$ has finite support.  This means their pointwise limit, if it exists, has *countable* support, and so it cannot equal $f$.

Comment: Did you want a (positive real?) coefficient in front of $1_{C_n}$?

Comment: @paulgarrett: Yes, thank you.  Fixed.

Comment: @Nate, thank you for your answer. I did not know that not all functions in a product space could be approximated starting from rectangle functions. I did not suspect this was actually the case because of the fact that the rectangles generate $\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}$. Can you maybe give me any reference or clarification on how the rectangle functions from a set of generators of a product $\sigma$-algebra are not enough to approximate all the functions that are measurable with respect to that product $\sigma$-algebra? I'd love to study this point more in-depth. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: There are various results about approximating measurable functions by rectangle functions in various modes - but not pointwise, and not from below.  For instance, I think it's true that the rectangle functions are dense in $L^p(E \times F, \mu)$ whenever $\mu$ is finite or $\sigma$-finite.  I don't have the precise statements or references off the top of my head.  [...]

Comment: But the central idea in all the proofs I know is to use either the monotone class lemma or the Dynkin $\pi$-$\lambda$ lemma, or their functional versions.  You would use similar techniques to fill in the gap in your proof.  One possible source is [Bruce Driver's lecture notes](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/240A-C-2016-17/Lecture_Notes/2012%20Notes/240Lecture_Notes_Ver8.pdf), chapters 11, 12, 16 and 31.

Comment: One essential piece that's easy to overlook: you will need to use more than simply the property that rectangles generate $\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}$.  For instance in the $\pi$-$\lambda$ approach, you will use the property that the intersection of two rectangles is a rectangle.  As trivial as this seems, it is essential: there are counterexamples where you have a class $\mathcal{C}$, not closed under intersection, that generates a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$, and yet you can't approximate by functions of the form $f(x) = \sum a_n 1_{C_n}$, $C_n \in \mathcal{C}$ in any good way at all.

Comment: A simple counterexample is $F = \{a,b,c\}$ consisting of three points, $\mathcal{F} = 2^F$, and $\mathcal{C} = \{\{a,b\}, \{b,c\}\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate it a lot.