# If two functions differ on a set of positive measure, must their essential infima differ, too?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f,g : [0,1]^2 \to [0,1]$ are measurable functions differing on a set $P$ of positive Lebesgue measure. Claim: there exists $A, B \subseteq [0,1]$, each of positive measure, such that $$\operatorname*{ess\,inf}_{A \times B} f \neq \operatorname*{ess\,inf}_{A \times B} g.$$

Is this claim necessarily true? What worries me is that if $P$ is a general Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb R^2$, it need not contain any measurable rectangle of the form $A \times B$. Does this change if we restrict $P$ to being a Borel set?

Comment: Interesting question.  I tried some monotone class arguments but they all break down.

Comment: Incidentally, requiring that $P$ be Borel won't change anything.  Suppose there is a counterexample with $P$ not Borel.  We can find Borel functions $\tilde{f}, \tilde{g}$ with $\tilde{f} = f$ and $\tilde{g} = g$ almost everywhere.  Then for any positive-measure $A,B$ we have $$\newcommand{\essinf}{\operatorname*{ess\,inf}}\essinf_{A \times B} \tilde{f} = \essinf_{A\times B} f = \essinf_{A \times B} g = \essinf_{A \times B} \tilde{g}.$$  Yet the set $\tilde{P} = \{\tilde{f} \ne \tilde{g}\}$ is Borel and must be non-null since otherwise we'd have $f = \tilde{f} = \tilde{g} = g$ a.e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

In [Measurable rectangles inside a non-null set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42748/measurable-rectangles-inside-a-non-null-set) you can find a construction of a nonnegative, almost-everywhere finite, Borel function $k(x,y)$ which is essentially unbounded on every rectangle of positive measure.  So taking $f = 1/(1+k)$ gives a function with vanishing essential infimum on every rectangle of positive measure, yet $f$ is almost everywhere nonzero.  If we take $g=0$, we have a counterexample as desired.

Comment: As I feared... Thank you for the insight!