# Existence of a positive measure square in a positive measure set in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\overline{E}$ has a positive measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Can we always find $A,B \subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $\overline{A},\overline{B}$ is of positive measure in $\mathbb{R}$ and $A×B\subset E$ ?

I tried this but not sure. Can someone confirm?

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AOd6.jpg)

> *Proof:*  Let
> $$ M=\{(x,y) \in [0,1]\times[0,1] \mid x-y \not\in\mathbb{Q}\}.$$
> Then $|M|_2 = 1 > 0$.  So by inner regularity there exists a compact set $C \subseteq M$ such that $|C|_2 > 0$.  Now let $E = C$.  Then $\overline{E} = C$) (since $C$ is closed), which implies that $|\overline{E}|_2 > 0$.

> If possible let $\exists A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $A\times B \subseteq E$ and $|\overline{A}|_1, |\overline{B}|_1 > 0$.  Then $$\overline{A}\times\overline{B} = \overline{A\times B} \subseteq \overline{E} = C \subseteq M. $$
> So $M$ contains a positive measured square, which is a contradiction.  Hence the answer to the question is **no**.

Comment: Just a partial consideration, but if $E$ has an interior point, you can always inscribe a square completely contained in it and split it into its two dimensions.

Comment: A partial answer: using the regularity theorem, one can find closed subsets of positive measure $C, D \subseteq {\Bbb R}$ that are contained respectively in $\pi_1(\overline{E})$ and $\pi_2(\overline{E})$ (projections of $\overline{E}$ onto the two coordinates). Thus, $C \times D \subseteq \overline{E}$. I wonder if there's a way of finding "smaller" subsets whose product will be contained in $E$.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of MathJax'ing your written work.  In the future, please familiarize yourself with the [MathJax syntax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and type up your work, rather than relying on an image, which is inaccessible to those using screen readers, and which makes indexing for search difficult.

Comment: @bof7 if i ignore the closure thing then u said that the answer to the question mentioned in title is positive. Can you say why?

Comment: No, that was just a bad guess on my part. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the **title** question is that **no**, a Borel measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ need not contain a measurable rectangle of positive measure. See the first answer to the following: [Measurable rectangles inside a non-null set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42748/measurable-rectangles-inside-a-non-null-set).